# Migrating legacy data with ef core is very slow

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

So quick background. I am working on setting up code to migrate a legacy database which is a mess in numerous way to a new database designed code first in Entity Framework Core. I have made new models for the new database and auto generated the old database in ef core to simplify things.

One of the tables i'm creating is based on 2 tables in the legacy database that have essentially the same data (but different models), which combined represent a little over 300,000 rows. Therefore, I am making 300,000 of the new database models along with their related tables totaling about 1.2 million rows in the new database.

My problem is that when I run a test of about 1000 rows and extrapolate the time to complete the whole migration, it comes out to about 3.5 hours. This feels very slow even for such a large number of rows.

Note, both databases are local to my computer so any network delays wouldn't affect it

Here is an example of the logic of my code:

```
//old rows are selected earlier in the function from the legacyDbContext
//provider = IServiceProvider. I use dependency injection for this
foreach(var oldRow in oldRows)
{
    using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
    {
        var legacyDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LegacyDbContext>();
        var newDatabaseDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<NewDatabaseDbContext>();
        var newRow = new NewRow();
        newDatabaseContext.NewRows.Add(newRow);
        newDatabaseContext.SaveChanges(); //generates the id for the newRow
  
        //transfer data from oldRow to newRow with some very light processing
        //Example
        newRow.Name = oldRow.Name;
        newRow.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(oldRow.IsActive) 
        //for some reason boolean values were saved as C# short ints 
        //which corresponds to tinyint on the database side

        var oldRelatedItems = legacyDbContext.oldRelatedItems
            .Where(m => m.oldItemId = oldItem.Id)
            .ToList();
        //in generally this list's count is only 2, sometimes 3
        foreach(var oldRelatedItem in oldRelatedItems) 
        {
            var newRelatedItem = new NewRelatedItem();
            newDatabaseContext.NewRelatedItems.Add(newRelatedItem);

            newRelatedItem.newItem = newItem;

            //transfer data from oldRelatedItem to newRelatedItem

            newDatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
     
        //Some more data transferred

        newDatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

One note here is that the legacy database does not have any foreign keys. There are columns which contain the id of rows in other tables but they are not configured as foreign keys (I told you this database was messy). So that may present itself as a bottleneck.

I have tried a couple of things that have been mostly ineffective. I tried running the foreach loops entirely inside the using statement, only saving the context 1 time at the end. This saved some time, but not much (5 minutes of 215 or so).

I also tried running the for loops as Parallel.ForEach loops but and actually saw the extrapolated time increase with this approach (could be I used this function incorrectly though).

Any thoughts on how I could improve my code's performance? The final migration will only have to be run 1 time as this whole project is being rebuild from the ground up (it really is THAT bad). Even still, I would like to know how to improve this, for my own understanding and so that maybe the migration won't take days (remember this question is all for just a couple tables).

Comment: It seems to me like a well-crafted SQL statement would execute much faster than this code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this.

Main themes are:

- take the context creation out of the loop
- try using bulk insert for everything at the end

  ```
   using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
   {
       //can this live outside the loop?
       var legacyDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LegacyDbContext>();

       var newRows = new List<NewRow>();
       var newRelatedItems = new List<NewRelatedItem>();

       foreach(var oldRow in oldRow){
           var newRow = new NewRow();

           newRow.Name = oldRow.Name;
           newRow.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(oldRow.IsActive);

           var oldRelatedItems = legacyDbContext.oldRelatedItems
               .Where(m => m.oldItemId = oldItem.Id)
               .ToList();

           foreach(var oldRelatedItem in oldRelatedItems) 
           {
               var newRelatedItem = new NewRelatedItem();

               //is this supposed to be newRow?
               newRelatedItem.newRow = newRow;
               //newRelatedItem.newItem = newItem;

               newRelatedItems.Add(newRelatedItem);
           }
       }

       var newDatabaseDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<NewDatabaseDbContext>();
       newDatabaseDbContext.BulkInsert(newRows);
       newDatabaseDbContext.BulkInsert(newRelatedItems);
   }
  ```

Comment: I will try this. And yes it is supposed to be newRow. Obviously these aren't the real names and I didn't double check for consistency apparently.